# Property 'Editor' does not exist on type 'MyComponent'. Angular 11.0.5

Tags: angular

please i'am using ckeditor in my angular app but not work with me. this wat i do
i install this packages

```
npm install --save @ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular
```

after i'am install this packages

```
npm install --save @ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic
```

in app module i'am adding this import

```
import { CKEditorModule } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular';

import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

imports: [CKEditorModule,FormsModule]
```

and in my components i try to add this

import * as ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
public Editor = ClassicEditor;

```
<ckeditor [editor]="Editor" ></ckeditor>
```

but she give me this error
"Property 'Editor' does not exist  on type 'MyComponent'" Angular 11.0.5

Answer (score 1):

You need to add import to the component in which you are using the Editor.

As stated in the documentation
https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/angular.html

Looks like you missed one step